# convert XRD to WSDL/WADL

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl, wadl

I want to create a REST client in Java using definitions. I cannot control the server. The service provides me some XRD documents defining it, but my Java tool (Apache CXF) can generate  Java classes only from WADL or WSDL documents.

I know that XRD is not the same than WSDL nor WADL, but:

Is there any tool to convert XRD to WSDL or WADL?

Comment: [XRD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Resource_Descriptor)? Is it just me, or is WADL a lot more comprehensible by mortal programmers?

Comment: @DonalFellows maybe WADL is more comprehensive, but I need to consume the service and it does not provide WADL, only XRD.